# "He hadn't realized there'd been a lightning storm brewing." Why is past perfect used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-perfect

I'm seeing past perfect more often in these types of sentences and it doesn't make sense. What makes it different from using simple past here?
Edit: Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense?

Comment: You're not giving us enough context to judge.

Comment: It depends on whether the writer is reporting now about stuff then, or is speaking as if they were observing then.  Part of the "voice" of the narration -- there's a specific term for this but I can't remember it.

Answer (score 0):

The man saw that a storm was starting (past tense). Until then he *had not realised* that the storm was on its way. The time when he might have said to himself "There's a storm brewing," obviously came *before* the storm began, so it is referred to in the past perfect.

Comment: Okay: brewing, storming, then realising. Wouldn't it be simpler to say *He DID not realise there HAD been a lightning storm brewing*? Right now we have "had...realized" and "had been...brewing"?

Comment: But it's not true to say that 'he did not realise there had been a storm brewing' after the storm had already started! It's looking back to his state of mind before the storm.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the choice of perfect vs non-perfect is almost entirely in the choice of the speaker or writer, how they wish to portray the temporal relations.

*Up to now he hadn't realised* puts the temporal focus at the time that he had that realisation. *Up to now he didn't realise* does not put the temporal focus anywhere in particular.

Having said that, in this case the perfect seems much more natural to me than the simple past. I think this may be because the "up to now" sets a sort of focus at the same place. But that explanation doesn't entirely work, because in other contexts we often do not use the past perfect when we could, if the temporal relationships are clear in other ways. So I can't clearly account for why the past perfect is more natural here.

Answer (score 0):

The past perfect is used

1) Most usually, but not exclusively, in **written** narrative to describe the first, or a series of, completed action(s), states, or event(s) in the past: It is especially used in narrative to set the background and context to following events that are then recorded in the simple past. e.g. "I **had dug** the garden and now **started** to wash he car."

2) In conditional usage e.g. If I **had had** 5 dollars more, I **would have** bought butter instead of margarine);

3) With words like "when, before, after, as soon as, once" in sentences with consecutive actions to emphasise that they are not connected.

(Compare:

(a) I **opened** the window and my cat **jumped** (The cat jumped because I had opened a window).

(b) I **had opened** the window and my cat **had jumped**. (The two actions are quite separate. The past perfect sets the context for the simple past;

5) In sentences, introduced by "It was the first/second/best/only/worst etc. (It was the first time I **had heard** her sing);

6) In sentences introduced by "Before" to express that something happened before someone had done something else (He went out before I **had finished** my sentence).